# Get string Array value

Tags: android, arrays

I am adding value to stringArray string array as below

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String [] stringArray = stringArrayList.toArray(new String[stringArrayList.size()]);

stringArrayList.add("values");
```

How can I get each of stringArray  array value within a loop

Comment: Kindly explain question properly and show what have you tried so far!

Comment: i adding image file names to array on image click.
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        String ImagePathToActivity = arg0.getTag().toString();
                        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ImagePathToActivity, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        stringArrayList.add(ImagePathToActivity);
                    }  });

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question:

```
for(String str: stringArrayList ){
  System.out.println(str) //or whatever you want
}
```